# Docker - Timezones in containers not same as on host

Tags: docker, time, host, timezone, containers

In all my running docker containers the containers system time is set to UTC whereas on my host (debian) its CEST.

Why dont they sync automaticly? How do i make them set the right time when bringing them up?

```
root@v2201510680628925:/home/jacob# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:36:47 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.2
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   b9f10c9
 Built:        Wed Jun  1 21:36:47 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
root@v2201510680628925:/home/jacob# date
Wed Aug  2 09:59:20 CEST 2017
root@v2201510680628925:/home/jacob# docker exec -it naos_nginx bash
root@0cefa7f7096c:/# date
Wed Aug  2 07:59:34 UTC 2017
root@0cefa7f7096c:/# exit
exit
root@v2201510680628925:/home/jacob# docker exec -it ah_avail bash
root@da52e8f3f61f:/usr/src/app# date
Wed Aug  2 07:59:59 UTC 2017
root@da52e8f3f61f:/usr/src/app# exit
exit
root@v2201510680628925:/home/jacob#
```

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to set timezone in your containers by using tzdata :

```
docker run -e TZ=Europe/Amsterdam debian:jessie date
```

Credits and further explanation to "Why containers don't sync time with host" : [Docker Container time & timezone (will not reflect changes)](https://serverfault.com/questions/683605/docker-container-time-timezone-will-not-reflect-changes)

Comment: thx, strange that it does not take the tz from the host ...

Comment: From `docker-compose.yml`, it's `TZ: yourtzname` under the `environment` key.