# Alpine Linux timezone doesn't stick if tzdata is removed

Tags: docker, timezone, date, alpine

This used to work to set the timezone. I have a container on Alpine 3.9.4 where it worked:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ America/Chicago
RUN apk del tzdata
```

I'm now creating a Docker container with Alpine Linux v3.10.3, and it doesn't work anymore. A user suggested that I need to copy to /etc/localtime:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ America/Chicago
RUN cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apk del tzdata
```

Neither of these work if `tzdata` is removed. However, they work if `tzdata` is not removed. Why is this?

[Related Question](https://serverfault.com/a/683651/352016)

Comment: Interesting. It doesn't work on alpine:latest. As soon as I remove tzdata, the container decides it's going to be UTC.

Comment: This _question_ was the _answer_ to my problem. :) Crazy that this single StackExchange post seems to be the only place on the Internet that mentions this behavior.

Comment: @sizzlebeam Glad to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package tzdata contains information about the time zones. It tells software that the zone CEST is UTC+02:00, and when it's in use.

When you remove the tzdata package all you have left is a variable with a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the *setup-timezone* script from *alpine-conf* package for that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

So I copy the /etc/localtime back to /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ and it works fine for me. here is my solution:

```
ENV TZ America/Chicago  
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-tz tzdata;\
    cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone;\
    apk del .build-tz;\
    echo /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ | cut -d'/' -f-5 | xargs mkdir -p;\
    cp /etc/localtime /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ
```